# Need help using VBA to prompt an email send when product quantity gets too low

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to use VBA to prompt the user to send an email to the administrator when the quantity of a products dips below the Reorder Quantity. All the parts are listed in a table in Excel and the Total Quantity column is next to the reorder quantity column. I have some code written, but I can't get the conditions to work to allow the email to pop up when the QTY drops below the Reorder QTY. My code is below. The issue I am having is that when the qty drops below the RO quantity, nothing is happening. Any advice?  DISCLAIMER I am brand new to VBA, so I am sorry if this code is jibberish.

```
Private Sub Reorder_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Intersect(Range("I5:I100"), Target)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value <= Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Sheets("Inventory List").Range("I5:J52"), 2, False) Then
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim xOutApp As Object
Dim xOutMail As Object
Dim xMailBody As String
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
xMailBody = "Part needs to be reordered" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Part Number: " & vbNewLine & _
"This is line 2"
On Error Resume Next
With xOutMail
.To = "ES ADMIN"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Reorder parts!"
.Body = xMailBody
.Display 'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you change `Worksheet_Change` to `Reorder_Change`?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I had it as Worksheet_Change it flagged me as having an ambiguous title

Comment: You can't change the handler, and you can only have one of them.

Comment: Looks like you want this code to run each time the user makes a change to any cell on a worksheet. So the first sub should be named `Worksheet_Change` and placed in a worksheet code module. The other sub should be placed in a general code module. Then, when your code does call `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` try using `Debug.Print` to check the return value of the `VLOOKUP` to make sure the value is value and what you expect.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. This part is working now!